# How to sort value in a nested list?

Tags: python, json, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list looks like this:

```
[[{'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Sushi Kashiba',
   'estimated_cost': 180,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.9, 'votes': 4175},
   'id': 31},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Peninsula Grand Hotel',
   'estimated_cost': 120,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.9, 'votes': 644},
   'id': 32},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Plum by Bent Chair',
   'estimated_cost': 180,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.9, 'votes': 1657},
   'id': 36},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': "R' ADDA",
   'estimated_cost': 120,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.9, 'votes': 4255},
   'id': 39},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Lord of the Drinks',
   'estimated_cost': 150,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.8, 'votes': 2086},
   'id': 34}],
 [{'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Hitch',
   'estimated_cost': 120,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.8, 'votes': 3277},
   'id': 311},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Hi Lounge',
   'estimated_cost': 120,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.7, 'votes': 1687},
   'id': 315},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Vedge',
   'estimated_cost': 10,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.7, 'votes': 3837},
   'id': 320},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Social',
   'estimated_cost': 140,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 7838},
   'id': 313},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'BKC DIVE',
   'estimated_cost': 10,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 5687},
   'id': 316}],
 [{'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Yauatcha',
   'estimated_cost': 280,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.8, 'votes': 5359},
   'id': 330},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': "Joey's Pizza",
   'estimated_cost': 80,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 8289},
   'id': 321},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Fun Republic Social',
   'estimated_cost': 90,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 2914},
   'id': 323},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'English Kitchen',
   'estimated_cost': 150,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 1887},
   'id': 324},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Pi Bar and Kitchen',
   'estimated_cost': 160,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 1927},
   'id': 325}],
 [{'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Palladium Social',
   'estimated_cost': 140,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.9, 'votes': 4892},
   'id': 332},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Bayroute',
   'estimated_cost': 300,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.8, 'votes': 1466},
   'id': 333},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'HOP : House of Party',
   'estimated_cost': 160,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.7, 'votes': 813},
   'id': 331},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Jimis Burger',
   'estimated_cost': 70,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.6, 'votes': 3680},
   'id': 335},
  {'city': 'Denver',
   'name': 'Garage Inc. Public House',
   'estimated_cost': 150,
   'user_rating': {'average_rating': 4.5, 'votes': 684},
   'id': 334}]]
```

I want to compare the value for `average_rating` and return the highest top 5 (if the numbers are the same then display based on the original order)

Expected output:

```
Sushi Kashiba
Peninsula Grand Hotel
Plum by Bent Chair
R' ADDA
Palladium Social
```

Comment: Why can you not sort it like you would sort anything else?

Comment: Downvote for the reason @martineau stated.  Getting tired of zero-effort requests for code.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I did try multiple methods, the key here (based on the solutions below) is that I need to flatten the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the list and then use `sorted` with the required key.

##### Solution:

```
#assuming your list is "my_list"
flattened = [i for lst in my_list for i in lst]
>>> [d["name"] for d in sorted(flattened, 
                               key=lambda x: x["user_rating"]["average_rating"], 
                               reverse=True)[:5]]
['Sushi Kashiba',
 'Peninsula Grand Hotel',
 'Plum by Bent Chair',
 "R' ADDA",
 'Palladium Social']
```

##### Explanation:

1. Flatten your list of lists to a list using list comprehension

   ```
   flattened = [i for lst in my_list for i in lst]
   ```
2. Sort the list of dictionaries on "average_rating":

   ```
   sorted_dicts = sorted(flattened, key=lambda x: x["user_rating"]["average_rating"], reverse=True)
   ```
3. Keep only the top 5

Answer (score 1):

If `lst` is your list from the question:

```py
for val in sorted(
    [v for l in lst for v in l],
    key=lambda k: k["user_rating"]["average_rating"],
    reverse=True,
)[:5]:
    print(val["name"])
```

Prints:

```
Sushi Kashiba
Peninsula Grand Hotel
Plum by Bent Chair
R' ADDA
Palladium Social
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools

```py
import itertools
# flattens list and take top 5. Negative sign because we want high->low
res = sorted(list(itertools.chain(*l)), key=lambda x: -x['user_rating']['average_rating'])[:5] 
for r in res:
    print(r['name'])
```